# Kubernetes service - How to differentiate identical target ports

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have two different deployments creating two different pods that spins up two different containers serves different purposes. but as a coincidence the port being exposed by both of those containers is 8080.

I created a single service with two ports 8080 and 8081(type=LoadBalancer) to expose both of those deployments. when I hit the LoadBalancer url I get back response from container 1 and after hitting refresh few times I get back the response from container 2. This behavior is same on both ports.

I know that changing the port exposed on the dockerfile of one of those containers would solve this problem. but just out of curiosity as a newbie to the kubernetes, is there any different approach to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Ingress. Here is an example.

Instead of creating one Service for both pods. Create one Service per pod. Make sure the selector labels are different for both. Set type to NodePort. Then create an Ingress with rules like.

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cafe.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /tea
        backend:
          serviceName: tea-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /coffee
        backend:
          serviceName: coffee-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

Now there are many ingress solutions out there. Ingress in k8s is just a networking spec. All it is, is a data model that represents your networking logic. The various ingress controllers take that spec and implement the logic with their given solution. Here is a link to the docs for nginx ingress controller. https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/kubernetes-ingress-controller/